# Why does WordPress use serialize rather than json_encode for the options table?

Tags: options, migration, json

I have a basic understanding of [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) (I come across it often when I'm migrating WordPress installs) and I just discovered [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Given that serialize causes so much trouble with replacing strings in the database (eg. editing an optinos field directly), why does WordPress prefer serialize to (the
seemingly similar) json_encode, which doesn't insert the string length into the stored value.

My first thought was that it may provide some security or error-checking benefits - WordPress will ignore the option if the string lengths are incorrect.. but I'm interested in a qualified explanation :)

Comment: If you use the search replace tool here: http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ then you can replace strings in serialised form too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804045/preferred-method-to-store-php-arrays-json-encode-vs-serialize

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183475/why-wordpress-choose-data-serialization-over-json-encode

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- serialize representation can be stored in text and reversed
- JSON representation can be stored in text but cannot always be precisely reversed

Run this example:

```
$query = new WP_Query();
var_dump( $query );
var_dump( unserialize( serialize( $query ) ) );
var_dump( json_decode( json_encode( $query ) ) );
```

- After going through serialize accurate `WP_Query` object is re-created.
- After going through JSON you get `stdClass` object.

In a nutshell serialize is native part of PHP and has a lot of synergy with manipulating data in it. JSON is language-agnostic format that is convenient for systems talking to each other, but far from comprehensive and cannot do things in PHP which serialize does without second thought.

Comment: I knew there had to be a good reason :) thanks @rarst

Answer (score 3):

See here for a good discussion on the reasoning behind not changing it to JSON:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23753